# When I upload csv file it throws 500 error

Tags: angular

I want to upload a csv file on upload button click, but gives 500 error. Previously it used to throw 415 error. After I made changes by adding  multipart/form-data, it started to throw 500 error

Here is my code

```
getFileDetails (e) {
    console.log (e.target.files[0]);
    this.myFiles=<File>e.target.files[0];
    console.log( this.myFiles);

  }
  uploadFiles () { 

    const frmData = new FormData();
    console.log(frmData);
    //console.log(this.myFiles);   
    frmData.append('file[]', this.myFiles);  

         this.http
         .post('url' +'test',
         frmData, {
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
             },

           }
         ).subscribe((data: any) => {
           this.resData = data;
           console.log(this.resData);
         });
}
```

Comment: Did you check server log for exceptions?

Comment: No.But url with postman works fine.should i check logs once?

Comment: what is the error message shown in the console ?

Comment: also note that here you are just selecting  one file `this.myFiles=<File>e.target.files[0];` and you are appending this one file as an array of files  to the form data `frmData.append('file[]', this.myFiles); ` it should have been `frmData.append('file', this.myFiles); `

Comment: @JoelJoseph ok thanks,error->500 status error